# Equation errors - I want to use units in the equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

I´m trying to get some simple equations into my document. However it seems my used units are not equation friendly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV10,12pt,headsepline,headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,
labelsep=endash,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\onehalfspacing
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage {picins}

\begin{gather}
Thickness&=\frac{100 $\mu$g/$\mathrm{cm}^{2}$}{8.38 $\mu$g/$\mathrm{cm}^{3}$} \\[1ex]
Thickness&=0.199 $\mu$m
\end{gather}
```

The equation should give me something like:
Thickness = (100 µg/cm²) / (8.38 µg /cm³)    [without brackets of course]

It seems that my unit definitions are not working properly in equations. There is no problem while using them in a normal text.

I really appreciate any hints!

(hope I used the correct tags)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To make life for people trying to help you easier, have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. Your question would be easier to answer, if you include \begin{document} and \end{document} in your code. Try as well to leave out all packages which are not required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a specialized package such as `siunitx` that make quite easy to input numbers and units; I'll show three ways to get the same output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV10,12pt,headsepline,headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{text-micro=\textmu,math-micro=\mathmu} % better micro symbol

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathit{Thickness}&=\frac{\SI{100}{\micro\gram/\centi\meter^{2}}}{\SI{8.38}{\micro\gram/\centi\meter^{3}}} \\[1ex]
\mathit{Thickness}&=\SI{0.199}{\micro\meter}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathit{Thickness}&=\frac{\SI{100}{\ug/\cm^{2}}}{\SI{8.38}{\ug/\cm^{3}}} \\[1ex]
\mathit{Thickness}&=\SI{0.199}{\um}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathit{Thickness}&=\frac{\SI{100}{μg/cm^{2}}}{\SI{8.38}{μg/cm^{3}}} \\[1ex]
\mathit{Thickness}&=\SI{0.199}{μm}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar I wanted to show three input styles, so it took me a couple of minutes more than you.

Comment: Hehe, I was joking. Your `μ` is really beautiful. +1 for that. :-)

Comment: If you want to show the three input styles, you should also include `\square`/`\squared` ad `\cubic`/`\cubed` as well as the more generic `\raiseto`/`\tothe` macros in the first two examples (the second only being an abbreviated version of the first).

Answer (score 3):

For units, you should be using `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV10,12pt,headsepline,headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[detect-all,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathit{Thickness} &=\frac{\SI{100}{\micro\gram \per \centi\meter^{2}}}{\SI{8.38}{\micro \gram \per \centi\meter^{3}}} \\[1ex]
\mathit{Thickness} &=\SI{0.199}{\micro \meter}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details, run `texdoc siunitx` from command line.

Further your equation with `gather` shouldn't have `&`. With gather, your equation will be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV10,12pt,headsepline,headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[detect-all,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\mathit{Thickness} =\frac{\SI{100}{\micro\gram \per \centi\meter^{2}}}{\SI{8.38}{\micro \gram \per \centi\meter^{3}}} \\[1ex]
\mathit{Thickness} =\SI{0.199}{\micro \meter}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please, `Thickness` should be `\mathit`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I could not see anything on LHS ;-)

Comment: hmmm.  `gather` enforces math mode.  just look at the gap between *T* and *h* -- as you have it, *Thickness* is just a bunch of letter variables multiplying one another.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are right. I was joking. Actually I looked only at the RHS. Thanks for the suggestion. I will correct it. :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar You should know that barbarabeeton is the best proof checker in the universe. But maybe she looked at my answer. ;-)

Comment: @egreg I know that she is right. But I didn't worry for correcting as your answer already existed. :-)

Comment: @egreg -- nah, i looked at your answer first to make sure you *did* do it right.  (and you did, of course.)